# How to filter photos in Lightroom 6 by EffectiveMaxAperture EXIF tag?

Tags: lightroom, metadata, manual-focus, tagging, photo-mechanic

I shoot with different non-CPU manual focus lenses and use [LensTagger](https://www.lenstagger.com/) (Lightroom plugin) to write full lens name into EXIF. I also set up different MF lens "profiles" (called "non-CPU lens data" by Nikon) in camera so it can register the correct f-stop and write it to the file metadata along with the lens focal length.

Two of my lenses are *50mm F/1.8* and *50mm F/2*. While photos shot with either of them already have *50mm* and the actual f-stop written into EXIF, I have trouble differentiating between them. The only time it's clear which lens was used is, obviously, when the photo was taken at f/1.8.

Thanks to ExifTool I have discovered that Nikon does write the programmed non-CPU lens data into EXIF. While the effective f-stop and lens focal length are pretty much on the surface and happily displayed by most programs, the maximum aperture value is written in *EffectiveMaxAperture* tag that doesn't seem to be displayed anywhere in Lightroom, Photo Mechanic or Nikon ViewNX 2.

Is there a way to filter photos in Lightroom by this tag, so I can select only photos taken with particular lens for further processing with LensTagger? Third party plugins are fine.

If no, then maybe there is a way to display *EffectiveMaxAperture* tag value in Photo Mechanic, so I could at least keyword the photos taken with the corresponding lens to be able to find them in Lightroom this way?

Answer (score 1):

You can customize the Metadata panel to show the Max Aperture tag. In the Metadata panel, click "Customize" at the bottom. Select "Max Aperture" under the "Camera Info" section, and that tag will now display in the panel.

[image]